# Flutter JNI error while running "flutter doctor --android-licenses"

Tags: java, android, flutter

I have installer flutter, android studio, android sdk and android sdk command line tools properly. Flutter doctor shows the following problems;

[image]

When I try to accept the licenses by running the command "flutter doctor --android-licenses", the following JNI error occurs:

[image]

I have installed the command line tools via Android studio

[image]

How do I fix this problem? Is this happening due to a java version mismatch?

Comment: The last screenshot have a checkbox "Show Package Details", tick that then be sure you have installed locally the same version specified in build.gradle by compileSdkVersion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Android licenses status unknown” is a warning not an error that cause the mis-compiling.

You probably have a version of Java/Android SDK related to your project minor to minimum requested by current flutter project related to its Android part.

Also You need to take a version that is the same in compileSdkVersion inside build.gradle (folder ../android/app/src/ build.gradle)  and SDK version selected for current project as images shows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it! I simply upgraded Java 8 to 11 and the problem was gone